# How to exclude already tracked files from git ls-files?

Tags: git, git-ls-files

Our team use flowtype, and git tracked files under the flow-typed directory. I want to hide those files shown by `git ls-files`.
Those files are already tracked, `—exclude` option does not seem to work, .git/info/exclude too.
Does anyone have good idea?

Comment: The main purpose of `git ls-files` is to show tracked files, so this question does not seem to make sense; but see `git ls-files --other` which shows only the *untracked* files.

Comment: That’s true for sure! Only a few team member needs those files, but noisy for me. so I want to hide them from `git ls-files`, but that’s not point, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Only a few team member needs those files, but noisy for me

Then you could consider marking those files as "unmodified" (even if they are) with it `update-index --assume-unchanged <filename>`.
That, in addition of using `git ls-files --other`, if you want to focus on untracked files.

As the [OP yakulto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10070755/yakulto) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51307462/how-to-exclude-already-tracked-files-from-git-ls-files/51317950?noredirect=1#comment89614325_51317950):

> `git ls-files` shows already tracked files anyway, because `git ls-files` to show tracked files!
>   If I feel noisy and don't want to show `ls-files` result, simply, I should use other command like `find`, `ls | grep`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried `git udpate-index --assume-unchanged flow-typed/npm/aws-sdk_vx.x.x.js` (it's aws-sdk's definition file), and then `git ls-files --other | grep flow-typed/npm/aws-sdk_vx.x.x.js`, nothing is shown. Did I make a mistake?

Comment: @yakulto Considering `git ls-files --other` shows only *untracked`files, that is expected: `flow-typed/npm/aws-sdk_vx.x.x.js` is tracked already. All what `git udpate-index --assume-unchanged flow-typed/npm/aws-sdk_vx.x.x.js` does is preventing it to show up in `git status` as modified: you would ignore any new modification.

Comment: Ok, now I see. `git ls-files` shows already tracked files anyway, because `git ls-files` to show tracked files! If I feel noisy and don't want to show `ls-files` result, simply, I should use other command like `find`, `ls | grep`. thanks @VonC and @torek!